# OAuth responses require a User Pool defined in config

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am unable to connect to userpool which I defined right above: Auth is an amplify Object

```
Auth.configure({
  region: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_REGION,
  userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_UNIFY_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
  userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_UNIFY_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,

  // Cognito Hosted UI configuration
  oauth: {
    domain: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_UNIFY_COGNITO_DOMAIN,
    scope: ['email', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin', 'profile'],
    redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000',
    redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000',
    responseType: 'code',
  },
});
```

I get this error in my browser :Unhandled Rejection (Error): OAuth responses require a User Pool defined in config
AuthClass.
What else is there to connecting programmatically to a user pool. I didn't do amplify push,add auth or anything with the amplify cli b/c I don't think it's necessary?

Comment: I was having same issue, resolved by changes in config file

Answer (score 2):

This is most often down to the fact that you have changed your `.env` file, but not stopped and restarted your local web server.

For instance if you use `yarn serve`, make sure you stop the process, then update your `.env`, then `yarn serve` again.